# ModuleNotFoundError after installing pyodbc with pip in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, pyodbc, modulenotfounderror

I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError` after installing `pyodbc` using `pip` in VSCode.
This has happened a few times before, e.g. after installing `pygame`, but after a few times it *somehow* works. This time it is not working at all.

I tried

- in my code: `import pip` gave me a ModuleNotFoundError
- in the terminal: `pip install pyodbc` and `pip3 install pyodbc` both say that the requirement is already satisfied. However when I run my code it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: Check out this article: https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/pip-command-not-found
It explains some common problems. It sounds like python just isn't in your path variables, so try using the article to debug the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you really installed the `pyodbc` package, but you don't necessarily use the python environment where the `pyodbc` package is installed.

##### Solution:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter` --> selects the **correct** interpreter.

*Don't forget to use the **Python** extension to execute the script (Run Python File).*