# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil' despite already being installed

Tags: python, pip

I have been trying to run a code of a log-in window that would later redirect to the main window and so far it works, however, from the terminal. I keep getting this error, even though the import is already installed:

```
  File "C:\Users\UserPC\Downloads\Test\ddd2.py", line 12, in <module>
    import loginpg
  File "C:\Users\UserPC\Downloads\Test\loginpg.py", line 6, in <module>
    import psutil
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psutil'
```

I did reinstall it numerous times and even upgraded pip just in case, but it's still giving me the same error. Any advice on how to fix this? For the record, the psutils version is: `psutil-5.9.8`, and I'm using VS Code as my code editor.

Comment: Does your python shell find it? Within the project environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError when I am installing pyodbc using pip in VSCode (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590614/modulenotfounderror-when-i-am-installing-pyodbc-using-pip-in-vscode-python)